# Function not executing on button click

Tags: javascript, html

Once again I'm having Javascript woes. I'm making a script that calculates the type, perimeter and area of a triangle given its sides' lengths, but the script I've written does not fire upon clicking the insert button.

```
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", triangleCheck);
        function triangleCheck(){
            var A = document.getElementById("a").value;
            var B = document.getElementById("b").value;
            var C = document.getElementById("c").value;
            var valido = function(){
                if((A < B+C) && (B < A+C) && (C < A+B)){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            };
            this.v=valido();
            this.perimetro = function(){
                if(valido() == true){
                    return A+B+C;
                }else{
                    return "triangolo non valido";
                }
            };
            var s = this.perimetro()/2;
            this.area = function(){
                if(valido() == true){
                    return Math.sqrt(s*(s−A)*(s−B)*(s−C));
                }else{
                    return "triangolo non valido";
                }
            };
            this.tipo = function(){
                if(valido() == true){
                    if(A == B && B == C && C == A){
                        return equilatero;
                    }else if(A == B || B == C || C == A){
                        return isoscele;
                    }else{
                        return scaleno;
                    }
                }else{
                    return "triangolo non valido";
                }
            };
            document.getElementById("periTri").innerHTML = this.perimetro;
            document.getElementById("areaTri").innerHTML = this.area;
            document.getElementById("tipoTri").innerHTML = this.tipo;
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Inserisci i tre lati del triangolo:</h3><br>
    <form id="lati">
      <label for="a">A</label>
      <input type="text" id="a" name="a"><br>
      <label for="b">B</label>
      <input type="text" id="b" name="b"><br>
      <label for="c">C</label>
      <input type="text" id="c" name="c"><br>
      <br>
      <button type="button" id="add" name="add" value="Inserisci"></button>
    </form>
    <ul id="periTri"></ul>
    <ul id="areaTri"></ul>
    <ul id="tipoTri"></ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't know what to do, I've tried everything I could find - including the right answer to a prior JS problem I've had - but nothing worked. In fact, it's a problem that continues to haunt me even after doing many JS exercises.

Comment: Did shows any error on console?

Answer (score 3):

Problem in your coding:

1. Script tag is before body tag.
2. Doesn't convert string values acquired from input to number

## Working Code Here

```js
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", triangleCheck);

function triangleCheck() {
  // input values are always string, cast them to numbers
  var A = Number(document.getElementById("a").value);
  var B = Number(document.getElementById("b").value);
  var C = Number(document.getElementById("c").value);
  var valido = function() {
    // if you don't cast string to number, below condition won't work
    if (A < B + C && B < A + C && C < A + B) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
  this.v = valido();
  this.perimetro = function() {
    if (valido() == true) {
      return A + B + C;
    } else {
      return "triangolo non valido";
    }
  };
  var s = this.perimetro() / 2;
  this.area = function() {
    if (valido() == true) {
      return Math.sqrt(s * (s - A) * (s - B) * (s - C));
    } else {
      return "triangolo non valido";
    }
  };
  this.tipo = function() {
    if (valido() == true) {
      if (A == B && B == C && C == A) {
        return "equilatero";
      } else if (A == B || B == C || C == A) {
        return "isoscele";
      } else {
        return "scaleno";
      }
    } else {
      return "triangolo non valido";
    }
  };
  document.getElementById("periTri").innerHTML = this.perimetro();
  document.getElementById("areaTri").innerHTML = this.area();
  document.getElementById("tipoTri").innerHTML = this.tipo();
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h3>Inserisci i tre lati del triangolo:</h3><br>
  <form id="lati">
    <label for="a">A</label>
    <input type="text" id="a" name="a"><br>
    <label for="b">B</label>
    <input type="text" id="b" name="b"><br>
    <label for="c">C</label>
    <input type="text" id="c" name="c"><br>
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="add" name="add" value="Inserisci">Inserisci</button>
  </form>
  <ul id="periTri"></ul>
  <ul id="areaTri"></ul>
  <ul id="tipoTri"></ul>
</body>
<!-- Move your script tag here !!! -->
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because the script executes before documents loading.

Try this:

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function onload() {
      document
        .getElementById('add')
        .addEventListener('click', triangleCheck);

      function triangleCheck() {
        // your logic here
        console.log('check');
      }
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onload);
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <!-- your content here -->
</body>
```

---

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

Answer (score 1):

You just need to execute script after creating all DOM elements. Because when you query a DOM element browser can't found it because it haven't created yet.

To solve this issue place `<script>` before closing `</body>` tag. Or add `onclick` attribute to `<button>`.

Check the working code:

```html
<body>
  <h3>Inserisci i tre lati del triangolo:</h3><br>
  <form id="lati">
    <label for="a">A</label>
    <input type="text" id="a" name="a"><br>
    <label for="b">B</label>
    <input type="text" id="b" name="b"><br>
    <label for="c">C</label>
    <input type="text" id="c" name="c"><br>
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="add" name="add" value="Inserisci"></button>
  </form>
  <ul id="periTri"></ul>
  <ul id="areaTri"></ul>
  <ul id="tipoTri"></ul>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", triangleCheck);

    function triangleCheck() {
      var A = document.getElementById("a").value;
      var B = document.getElementById("b").value;
      var C = document.getElementById("c").value;
      var valido = function() {
        if ((A < B + C) && (B < A + C) && (C < A + B)) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      };
      this.v = valido();
      this.perimetro = function() {
        if (valido() == true) {
          return A + B + C;
        } else {
          return "triangolo non valido";
        }
      };
      var s = this.perimetro() / 2;
      this.area = function() {
        if (valido() == true) {
          return Math.sqrt(s * (s - A) * (s - B) * (s - C));
        } else {
          return "triangolo non valido";
        }
      };
      this.tipo = function() {
        if (valido() == true) {
          if (A == B && B == C && C == A) {
            return 'equilatero';
          } else if (A == B || B == C || C == A) {
            return 'isoscele';
          } else {
            return 'scaleno';
          }
        } else {
          return "triangolo non valido";
        }
      };
      document.getElementById("periTri").innerHTML = this.perimetro();
      document.getElementById("areaTri").innerHTML = this.area();
      document.getElementById("tipoTri").innerHTML = this.tipo();
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

I also fixed some major issues. For example you re setting function to innerHTML instead of function result. To get function result you need to call it using `()`. That's it. The code is working now.